# How to store each iteration of an R for loop into a new list element?

Tags: r, loops

I am hoping to create a function that loops through a list of species and stores the output for each species' occurrences in the BIEN database in its own list element. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
library(BIEN)

species_list <- list(c("Lonicera hispida","Hylocomium splendens","Deschampsia antarctica"))

occurrences <- function(spp) {
  
  list_of_occ <- list()
  
  for(i in 1:length(spp)){
    df <- BIEN_occurrence_species(species = spp[[i]],
                                    cultivated = TRUE,
                                    all.taxonomy = TRUE,
                                    native.status = TRUE,
                                    observation.type = TRUE,
                                    political.boundaries = TRUE)
    list_of_occ[[i]] <- df
  }
  df_list <<- list_of_occ
}
occurrences(spp = species_list)
```

This returns df_list with 1 element that contains the species information for all 3 species in one data frame, but I want it to return the list with each species in its own element (so df_list[[1]] for species 1, df_list[[2]] for species 2, and df_list[[3]] for species 3)

Using R 4.2.2

Comment: You species list is a list of one element containing the vector `c("Lonicera...",..., "... antarctica")`. If you want it to be a list, don't use the `c(...)`.

Comment: Rather than using global assignment with `<<-` it's **much** better practice to `return(list_of_occ)` at the end of your function, and then you assign the result of the function when you call it, `df_list <- occurrences(spp = species_list)`. This gives you flexibility on the name of the result and will behave predictably even if it is used inside a function. The `<<-` approach on the other hand will be unexpected to most R users, it takes special handling if you run want to use results from different inputs at the same time, and it may not do what you want if called inside another function.